# How do I make my program responsive to highlighting and entering?

Tags: javascript

I was tasked to make a page where, when you highlight and press enter on one of the menus below, it would open up, and when you highlight and press enter again, it disappears. Except, I don't know how to get the program to respond to highlighting. This is the program I've written so far.

https://e33440.neocities.org/javascript.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please edit your question and add the code here as a snipper, there is a button in the editor. Also be more specific about the problem you are facing.

Comment: This definetly require some javascript. But in your example aren't any menus ...